# How to replace an embedded font with a standard system font in Acrobat X?

Tags: fonts, pdf, adobe-acrobat

In a large PDF document with several hundred pages there are abour 10 embedded fonts used.

Can I exchange a specific embedded font against a system font (like Arial or Courier) with a single command everywhere in the document?

(Of course I would try to use a font very similar in size and style to the original)

Answer (score 3):

I exported to MS Word and saved it as PDF again. This did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to do this in Acrobat X, but if you also have Illustrator, it can, and it can open and save PDFs. If it doesn't prompt you when you open the document, use the [**Find Font…**](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/fonts.html#find_and_replace_fonts) command in the **Type** menu. Missing fonts will be marked with a *****.

Answer (score -4):

I found this answer and it helped me fix the embedded missing font problem.

https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/correcting-problem-areas-preflight-tool.html

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain the solution

Comment: Link only answers are generally frowned upon, but there isn't even a solution behind that link. Preflight itself *may* be a solution but that page doesn't explain how in any way.